# angularjs push row index

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a form where users can add items by clicking "add item", it opens a modal view, search for item then select multi items and add those rows to the main form ( using push) 
JS :

In the modal in the table i have in every row with a td containing input text :

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="row in rowssearchinvitems" ng-class="{'selected' : row.selected}"
    ng-click="addItemFoundBySearch(row);"
<td>@{{row.PRODUCTCODE}}</td>
<td>@{{row.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION}}</td>
<td><input type="text" ng-model="qtyrequested[$index]"</td>
</tr>
</table>

<button ng-click="getAllSelectedRows();">add items</button>
```

then in js :

```
$scope.addItemFoundBySearch = function(row){
row.selected ? row.selected = false : row.selected = true;
};

    $scope.getAllSelectedRows = function() {
    var selectedrows = $filter("filter") ( $scope.rowssearchinvitems, {
    selected : true }, true);
    for (var i=0;i<selectedrow.length;i++) {
    var selectedrowsdata = selected[i];
    $scope.rowsrequests.push(selectedrows[i]);
};
```

The rows are pushing to the rows requests list (the table of the main form outside the modal), but the indexes are always different, i want :

if i opened the modal and i have for example :

```
Productcode   description    qty
1300          test          [   3500  ] (input text with index)
1500          test2         [         ] 
1800          test3         [  4000 ]
```

i selected test and test 3, the indexes selected are 0 and 2 BUT in the main form they are 0 and 1, i want to push and get same indexes because in the main form i have same rows, and quantity input (my main target is to fill the main quanity input with the quantity input inserted in the modal)

Comment: You can find the product in the main form and replace the quantity with what you have selected.

Comment: I know, but I have a task to put the quantity in the modal and push it with the row to the main form, any solution ?

Comment: Then you can push to a specific index in the main form

Comment: so how ? in the 2 tables rows are dynamic, i want to push every index to the same index in the main table

Comment: Get the index of the row in the modal table by $index and push to main table by $scope.rowsrequests.splice(i, 0, selectedrows[i]);

Comment: ok now It's pushing the rows from 0 and up, every new row pushed is set in the begin of the main table but the value in the input in the modal table not pushing to to the value of the input text in the main

Comment: isin't it possible to push the row directly to the second table ? without taking care of indexes? like push .. the row and the input type text with its value comes to the next table